# drupal multilingual frontpages different templates

Tags: 6, theming

I am building multilingual site using 3 languages.
English is default and 2 other used wit prefixes. www.example.com/fr/.../cs/

I would like to create custom landing page on www.example.com using different template than other landing pages with prefixes.

So www.example.com (which is English language) would only be plain page (custom template) with links to www.example.om/fr (with default template page) and to www.example.com/cs (default template)

Would be something like this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Which (major) version of Drupal are you using for the site?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention - it is drupal 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom template file for the English landing page first (for example: `page-customfront.tpl.php`) then add the following code into your theme template.php file:

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  global $language;
  if (drupal_is_front_page() && $language->language == 'en') {
    $variables['template_file'] = 'page-customfront';
  }
}
```

This should do the trick (assuming English will remain the default language with no prefix). Don't forget to switch out `mytheme` in the function name with your actual theme name.

As for the language links you could use the following code:

```
<?php
$langs = language_list();
foreach ($langs as $lang) {
  if ($lang->enabled) {
    if ($lang->language == 'en') continue;
    print l($lang->native, '<front>', array('language' => $lang));
  }
}
?>
```

This should go into `page-customfront.tpl.php` in the place where you want the links to appear. If you are familiar with creating custom modules or don't mind learning it would probably be preferable to turn this code into a function, add it your module file, enable the module and then just call the function from `page-customfront.tpl.php`.

Comment: Ok I will try that and let you know today. I am planning to add more languages in the future - all with prefixes, english language as well. Now I don't use it for customers - that is why I don't need prefix. What would I need to do to have www.example.com as a custom template with links to default templates with language prefixes? Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: This solution worked perfectly. Would you be so kind and tell me somution for my second quiestion? Thank you very much

Comment: Added the answer to your second question in my post. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi,I added the second code inside the page-customfront.tpl.php but it shows only 2 other languages and not english. I need it to show all available languages so the customer can choose from them. Why is it better to make custom module and to avoid such code with links to be put into page? Thank you

Comment: `if ($lang->language == 'en') continue;` in the code means that English is skipped as it would just link to the page the user is already on. You could modify it to make it link to a different page or add a custom English language with a prefix that would be used as the actual English version of the site. About where the code is: it's just good habit to not put a lot of php code into template files, but nothing to really worry about even if you do.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answers. Maybe I didn't explained what I want to achieve well because of my bad english. I would like to be www.example.com to be independent from any language. Would that be possible? From this site I would like to have links to individual language pages with prefixes. I applied a patch that enables to set different frontpage for all languages. What I try to achieve is exactly the same as http://www.biovea.com/

Comment: To my knowledge you can't make www.example.com independent. I would suggest adding a second custom English language with "en" prefix, which would get you the result you want. The original English would then only be used for www.example.com while the other English would act as the actual English language of the site. I've used this approach myself a lot (for a different purpose though) and it works well. If necessary you could also switch the roles of the custom and original English languages.

Comment: Is it the right way how to do that written as the last answer in this article? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203794/translating-strings-in-drupal-with-no-english-default-in-the-code So I just upload any other language that would serve for the www.example.page? Do I get it correct? I searched for an english translation but since it is default there is none available for download.

Comment: The accepted answer written there is the right way. You don't need any English translations since the custom language will use the default Drupal language (English) already. Reread my previous comment and try things out - you're making a simple thing unnecessarily complicated for yourself. If you still get stuck after all this create a new question and explain your problem there.

Comment: Well, that was what I asked- you suggested to add second custom english language. How to do that? I understand what you mean but nobody in no forum explains how to do that. Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Same place where you normally add languages. Path would be like this: "www.example.com/admin/settings/language/add". Click on "Custom language" on the bottom part.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you for patience and kind answers.